# Manually Adding a Decimal Field to the Attributes Table

Tags: qgis

I am fairly new to QGIS and search as I might in the manual, training manuals and widely on the net I can't find an in-depth explanation of how to set up a Decimal Number (real) field in my attribute table properly.

I have a number of vector layers, each with a polygon on them.  I need to add a decimal field to manually insert a rate per 1,000 of the population.  The number is more than likely going to be between n.n and nn.n

I have tried all sorts of different width and precision figures, but either the field is too small to take the number, or it is large enough, but I can't get a decimal point in there.  Does this mean that the decimal number is less than one?

When I have entered some information into the cell and pressed Enter the cell always reverts to NULL.

Please help!

Thanks

Andy

Comment: If you have to deal with shapefile attribute tables a lot, then i would suggest the "table manager" plugin, which allows field reordering/renaming.

Comment: After you get it added you can decide how many decimal places to display/label/etc. so add precision for what you need and then change how you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "New Column" tool in attribute table of your layer.

Width represent the total number of digits.
Precision represents the number of decimals

**Examples:**

**Width 5 Precision 3**

- -2.001
- 99.999

**Width 3 Precision 1**

- 0.1
- 1.2
- 99.9

**Width 20 Precision 9**

- 11123456789.123456789

If your calculations are getting NULL values, first try to save and refresh your table attribute.

If the problem persist, make sure that the output of your calculus is a number and not a text.

Answer (score 3):

To add a decimal column follow these steps:

1. Open feature table
2. Start edit session on feature
3. Click New column button
4. Enter the following (precision refers to number decimal places), see caption below

[image]

Then, manually add or calculate values into your new column