# QGIS not saving CRS changes

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system

I'm trying to save a shapefile that came in EPGS:3005 coordinate system, so all the shapefile polygon points have 6 or 7 digits before the decimal point (e.g. 1223282.8231), and I want to save/convert the shapefile to EPGS:4326 or any other CRS that has 2 or 3 digits before the decimal point (i.e. longitude and latitude to be processed and uploaded to Google My Maps.

I've tried all the methods shown [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/how-can-i-change-the-projection-of-shapefile-in-qgis), and it appears like the layer properties have been saved as EPGS:4326, but when I run my python script (that creates the KML file for Google Maps) all the coordinates are still in the 6 or 7 digit format. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you tried method 3 and are using the new file, if so please add your python script

Comment: Yes, I've tried Method 3. Just to confirm: EPGS:4326 is the one I want to upload for Google My Maps, correct?

Comment: please edit your question

Comment: What part of the question needs editing? Anyways, here's the python script I wrote (I'm not great at Python either): https://pastebin.com/Ue2Ryt4z

Comment: You can check what coordinates are in the file by creating new fields (x and y), and using the field calculator > geometry to show what coordinates are stored in the file.

Comment: @LaurensBakker could you give me a step-by-step on how to do that?

Comment: add the python to the question not the comments

Comment: (out the top of my head)
1. Open the attribute table of the file
2. Add add two new fields of the type float/double(https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67272/manually-adding-a-decimal-field-to-the-attributes-table)
3. Calculate the X for the first field, and the Y for the second (http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html) Use $x and $y for the expression
4. Now you should be able to view the X and Y in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried all the methods shown here

Don't blindly apply things you do not understand!

I assume you did "2. Right click on vector layer > Set Layer CRS"? Now QGIS thinks your layer's coordinates are already EPSG:4326 so everything is broken.

Restart from scratch. Open QGIS to a blank project, load your Shapefile, then do "3. Right click on vector layer > Save As..." and there, and only there, choose EPSG:4326. A new file will be written and it will have coordinates transformed to EPSG:4326. Your original file will be left untouched.

Comment: Yes, this is what worked! My mistake was that I tried all three methods sequentially without resetting the shapefile.

"Don't blindly apply things you do not understand!" Very wise words!